# Copy string of characters from the middle of filename to the beginning

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filenames, rename

Have 2,000 files, each with 51-62 character-long filenames. For each filename, I would like to add the character-stretch in position 14-23 to the very beginning of the filename. (Filename character types and patterns are variable, so the rename must be based on position counting from the filename's beginning.)
Windows 7, command prompt FCIV solution preferred.

For example:

original:

abcdefghijklm**No0123456p**8901234567890.ext

new:

**No0123456p**abcdefghijklm**No0123456p**8901234567890.ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\folder"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "name=%%a"
 CALL :transform
)

GOTO :EOF

:transform
ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%name%" "%name:~13,10%%name%"
GOTO :eof
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

The variable `sourcedir` is `set` to point to the directory of interest. By setting a variable, the directoryname can be changed in one place rather than editing it in multiple places should it be used in multiple places. The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures any trailing spaces on the line are not included in the value assigned.

The `dir` command produces a list of filenames in the target directory `/b` means "filenames only - no header/trailer lines, no date, time size - just the filename" `/a-d` means "and no directory names"

This list is built in memory, and then read line-by-line by the `for/f`. The `"delims="` ensure that the entire line is applied to the metavariable `%%a` so that filenames that include default separators are not truncated. Each filename is then assigned to the variable `name` because substringing can't be applied directly to a metavariable. The subroutine `:transform` is then executed.

The subroutine is quite simple - all it does is `echo` a rename command, using the full filename built from the variables `sourcedir` and `name`. The syntax of the `ren` command requires that the new name is name-only, the subdirectory is implicit. The new name is built from the substring within `name` starting at character 13 (the first character is character `0`) for a length of 10 characters + the original name.

Since the `dir` list is built in memory before the `for` starts executing, the names delivered to the `for` are the original names. If a file has become renamed, it will not be re-processed as its new name is not in that original list.

The idea of `ECHO`ing the `ren` line is so that the user can see whether the `ren` commands generated are correct. All that happens is that a report is sent to the screen. If it is then determined that the result appears correct, then changing `echo ren` to `ren` will actually execute the rename rather than reporting it. That's a decision to be made by the user. If the resultant `ren` is wrong (wrong count of position or length, or wrong directory or whatever) then no harm is done as the product is simply a report until the job is run with `echo ren` changed to `ren`.

Comment: Thank you! What "dir /b /a-d" stands for, should I change it? Am I to change only ECHO REN to REN and ensure that the c:\sourcedir is correct or have to custimize other parameters?

Comment: It's a batch file for use from "command prompt". Don't know what else you may have expected, given that you tagged the query "Dos" and "batch-processing".

Comment: File to rename: C:\test

    C:\test>@ECHO OFF  
    SETLOCAL  
    SET "sourcedir=\C:\test"
    FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
    %%a was unexpected at this time.
     'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
    ''dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
     ) DO (
     SET "name=%%a"
     CALL :transform
    Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script.
    )
    
    GOTO :EOF
    
    :transform
    REN "%sourcedir%\%name%" "%name:~13,10%%name%"  
    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    GOTO :eof

Comment: Ouchh - Don't write every line into the command-window. Paste the whole stuff into a file named `Transform.bat` then just start that file by typing `transform`

Comment: Specified the actual folder in c:\folder, removed the ECHO from the ECHO REN, pasted the script into a notepad, named as Transform.bat. Works perfectly, thank you!!!